# Write PHP to find a word in a text file using a loop

Tags: php

Write PHP script to search for a word in a text file (titled a.txt). Text file contains 50 words, each word is on 1 line.  On the JavaScript side, a client types a random word in a text field and submits the word. The PHP script searches through the 50 words to find the correct word using a loop that runs until the word is found in the a `.txt` file.  If the word is not found, an error message must appear stating that the word was not in the list.

The JavaScript part is correct but I'm having trouble with PHP:

```
$file = fopen("a.txt","r") or die("File does not exist in the current folder.");
$s = $_POST["lname"];
$x = file_get_contents("a.txt");
$a = trim($x);
if(strcmp($s, $a) == 0)
print("<h1>" . $_POST["lname"] . " is in the list</h1>");
else
print("<h1>" . $_POST["lname"] . " is not in the list</h1>");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Your description and code do not match.

Comment: I don'n understand your question in the code.. where are you searching the word?? You have to read the file, make an explode("\n", $string) for example, and then use a loop to find the word in the array generated by the loop.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 3):

If it's only 50 words then just make an array out of it and check if it's in the array.

```
$file = file_get_contents('a.txt');
$split = explode("\n", $file);

if(in_array($_POST["lname"], $split))
{
    echo "It's here!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_in_file($lname) {
    $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 
    if ($fp) { 
        $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename))); 
        foreach ($array as $word) {
            if ($word == $lname)
                return True;
        }
    }
    return False;
}
```

Comment: Any explination of what you are doing or why?

Comment: That was the body of a function to perform the job. Added the signature.

Answer (score 0):

You are not searching the "word" into your code, but maybe the code below will help you

```
$array = explode("\n",$string_obtained_from_the_file);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value== "WORD"){
      //code to say it has ben founded
    }
}
//code to say it hasn't been founded
```

Answer (score 0):

here is something fancy, regular expression :)

```
$s = $_POST["lname"];
$x = file_get_contents("a.txt");

if(preg_match('/^' . $s . '$/im', $x) === true){
    // word found do what you want
}else{
    // word not found, error
}
```

remove the `i` from `'$/im'` if you do not want to the search to be case-insensitive
the `m` in there tells the parser to match `^$` to line endings, so this works.

here is a working example : http://ideone.com/LmgksA

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to break apart the file into an array if all you're looking for is a quick existence check.

```
$file = fopen("a.txt","r") or die("File does not exist in the current folder.");
$s = $_POST["lname"];
$x = file_get_contents("a.txt");

if(preg_match("/\b".$s."\b/", $x)){
    echo "word exists";
} else {
    echo "word does not exists";
}
```

This matches any word token in a string.

Comment: that would work...but i really need to use a loop to iterate through the 50 words that are contained in a text file. Each word is on a line. Do you have any idea how to do so?